# OSError: someObject.o: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm failing to load a shared object library with python. I've tried setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to where the `someObject.o` is located and that works when I am using non-sudo command to run the python script but when I use `sudo` I run into a linking error.

```
OSError: bbumintflib.o: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to link a `.o` file to the `.so` file?

using `ldd`, I know the `.so` cannot find the `.o` file.

```
>>>ldd someSharedObject.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffca69af000)
someObject.o => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f53c96b8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f53c9a57000)
```

Edit:

This is how I am building the object and sharedObject files

```
gcc -I ../include -I../../module1/include -I ../../module2/include --shared -fPIC someCFile.c -o someObject.o plat_linux.c

gcc someObject.o -shared -o someSharedObject.so
```

Comment: `.o` is not a shared library, it is an object file. A shared library has file ending `.so`. I don't know why it shows up in your `ldd` results. Seems that somehing went wrong when linking `someSharedObject.so`. `sudo` clears the environment variable, exactly so that you cannot inject some library into a root command. You should probably show how `someSharedObject.so` is built and installed.

Comment: @user17732522 I've added the commands I use to build the object and shared object files.

Comment: The step `gcc someObject.o -shared -o someSharedObject.so` is pointless. The previous command already produces a shared library. You are just naming it `.o` instead of `.so` against convention.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you, this ended up fixing it. It was my mistake on how I was building my library. Great catch to spot that upstream from where I thought the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
gcc -I ../include -I../../module1/include -I ../../module2/include --shared -fPIC someCFile.c -o someObject.o plat_linux.c
gcc someObject.o -shared -o someSharedObject.so
```

The first command produces a shared library with odd name `someObject.o`.
The second command links a new shared library named `someSharedObject.so`, which depends on `someObject.o`.

To fix this, do this:

```
gcc -I ... --shared -fPIC someCFile.c plat_linux.c -o someSharedObject.so
```

Comment: Thanks, that ended up fixing it for me. It was my mistake of how I built the libraries.